# Xamarin: Binding ios protocol/delegate can't access enum defined in structs.cs

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm currently in the process of creating ios bindings for the [EDQueue library.](https://github.com/thisandagain/queue)

The `Structs.cs` file looks something like this:

```
using System;
using ObjCRuntime;

namespace EDQueue
{


    // => Enums attributed with[NativeAttribute] must have an underlying type of `long` or `ulong`
    [Native]
    public enum EDQueueResult : long
    {
        Success = 0,
        Fail,
        Critical
    }

}
```

The `ApiDefinition.cs` file is something like:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;

namespace EDQueue
{
    // typedef void (^EDQueueCompletionBlock)(EDQueueResult);
    delegate void EDQueueCompletionBlock(EDQueueResult result);

    // ETC....

    // @protocol EDQueueDelegate <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface EDQueueDelegate
    {
        // @optional -(EDQueueResult)queue:(EDQueue *)queue processJob:(NSDictionary *)job;
        [Export("queue:processJob:")]
        EDQueueResult Queue(EDQueue queue, NSDictionary job);

        //// @optional -(void)queue:(EDQueue *)queue processJob:(NSDictionary *)job completion:(EDQueueCompletionBlock)block;
        //[Export("queue:processJob:completion:")]
        //void Queue(EDQueue queue, NSDictionary job, EDQueueCompletionBlock completeBlock);

    }

    // ETC...
}
```

As written, the following error is produced:
**Error CS0426: The type name 'EDQueueResult' does not exist in the type 'EDQueue' (CS0426) (EDQueue)** in file `EDQueueDelegate.g.cs`

That file looks like this when the error is thrown:

```
//
// Auto-generated from generator.cs, do not edit
//
// We keep references to objects, so warning 414 is expected

#pragma warning disable 414

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UIKit;
using GLKit;
using Metal;
using MapKit;
using ModelIO;
using SceneKit;
using Security;
using AudioUnit;
using CoreVideo;
using CoreMedia;
using QuickLook;
using Foundation;
using CoreMotion;
using ObjCRuntime;
using AddressBook;
using CoreGraphics;
using CoreLocation;
using AVFoundation;
using NewsstandKit;
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreFoundation;

namespace EDQueue {
    [Protocol (Name = "EDQueueDelegate", WrapperType = typeof (EDQueueDelegateWrapper))]
    [ProtocolMember (IsRequired = false, IsProperty = false, IsStatic = false, Name = "Queue", Selector = "queue:processJob:", ReturnType = typeof (EDQueue.EDQueueResult), ParameterType = new Type [] { typeof (global::EDQueue.EDQueue), typeof (NSDictionary) }, ParameterByRef = new bool [] { false, false })]
    public interface IEDQueueDelegate : INativeObject, IDisposable
    {
    }
// ETC...
}
```

However, if I remove or comment out the `[Protocol, Model]` bit, the library builds without error.

I'm also getting a similar error if I uncomment the second function with the `EDQueueCompletionBlock`, which ultimately relies on the `EDQueueResult` enum.

The `Structs.cs` file's build action is set to `ObjcBindingCoreSource`.

Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have by any chance also a _type_ named EDQueue (in addition to namespace with such name)?

Comment: @Evk, Thanks for replying. There is a class named EDQueue that keeps track of a singleton/shared instance and some other stuff. In the bindings, this comes out as an interface named EDQueue with a `[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]`.

Comment: So that is the reason - it thinks EDQueue.EDQueueResult is inner class of that EDQueue (does not treat EDQueue as namespace). Try to just use EDQueueResult or something like global::EDQueue.EDQueueResult.

Comment: @Evk, Easier to show directly. Can you take a look at this and confirm? Thanks!
https://github.com/Sitata/edqueue-xamarin/blob/master/EDQueue/ApiDefinition.cs#L37

Comment: Not sure what should I look at. As you said - you have interface with the same name as your namespace - and this is causing problems with statements like EDQueue.EDQueueResult - is that type in EDQueue namespace or child class of EDQueue type? Compiler chooses the latter.

Comment: EDQueue interface and EDQueueResult are both within the EDQueue namespace. From what you said, the compiler is choosing to look for a child class. I can confirm that if I change the namespace, everything compiles fine. What is the general solution to this? I'm new to Xamarin and the bindings process and so I'm not sure if changing the namespace is valid. Thanks for pointing out the cause!

Comment: General solution is just not have class with the same  name as namespace. This is not related to xamarin or bindings, just a general c# rule. If you must do this - look my comment above about how you can reference such class without renaming anything.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have both namespace `EDQueue` and type (interface) named `EDQueue` - you cannot reference any type in namespace `EDQueue` with `EDQueue.TypeName`, so this statement:

```
ReturnType = typeof (EDQueue.EDQueueResult)
```

Will not compile, because compiler will search for a member inside `EDQueue` interface (even though interfaces cannot have child classes, nor static members) and not inside `EDQueue` namespace.

Most obvious way to fix this is to not ever have namespace and type with the same name, so rename either namespace or type name.

If that is not possible or you are not completely sure it will not have side effects - change reference to

```
ReturnType = typeof (EDQueueResult)
```

and add `using EDQueue` to the usings block. Alternatively, reference like this:

```
ReturnType = typeof (global::EDQueue.EDQueueResult)
```